# Dafny: Not checking multiple predicates

Tags: dafny

Currently, I tried to write a balanced version (AVL-Tree) of the existing Binary-Tree in the Dafny Repo.
It was possible for me to verify that this balanced tree is still a valid Binary-Tree.

To verify that it also suffices the requirements of an AVL-Tree, I created two additional predicates.
These predicates verify that the height of the subtree is valid and that the node and its subtree is balanced.

As the height validity check requires a valid Binary-Tree and as the balance check requires a valid height calculation the predicates depend on each other:

```
  predicate Heigth_Valid() 
    reads this, Repr 
  {
    Valid() &&
    (..)
  }

  predicate Balanced() 
    reads this, Repr
  {
    Valid() &&
    Heigth_Valid() &&
    (..)
  }

  predicate Valid()
    reads this, Repr
  {
    (..)
  }
```

Thus it is possible to split the verification for different methods as some might only provide a valid Binary-Tree, while others recalculate the height or balance the tree.

The verification that the tree is balanced was successful,
but when I tried to check the verification with counterexamples and altered the code to produce an unbalanced tree, Dafny showed no errors in the IDE.
Is it possible that Dafny ignores certain predicates?

Comment: Dafny does not ignore any predicates. This sounds more like some issue with the counterexample mode or possibly with the caching of verification results. Try it from the command line to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Using Dafny 2.3.0 from the command line, no errors occurred as well. It is possible to compile the project and run it within VSCode and directly from the command line.

Comment: After I installed VSCode and Dafny on another VM it showed the same results. I published the initial version on [GitHub](https://github.com/rposchinger/Dafny-AVL-Tree)